# Handling Event Bubbling in Nested Popup(s) (Portals) semantic-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, semantic-ui

Imagine the following setup

```
<Popup closeOnDocumentClick={true}>
    <Popup><button onClick={e=> e.stopPropagation()}>Click Me!</button></Popup>
</Popup>
```

Clicks on the inner popup counts as a **document click** therefore closes the 1st popup. This is because even though these are logically nested in the React Virtual DOM, on the rendered page they are parallel **div(s)**

How can we prevent this behavior? i.e. prevent clicks on the inner Popup from being treated as a outer Popup closing click?

## Solution 1

Conditionally turn off `closeOnDocumentClick` if the inner Popup is open

I do not like this solution, because the inner Popup could be abstracted by as a Component, I don't want to create additional coupling

## Solution 2

I don't have a solution 2

Comment: I don't know React but through `event.target` is possible to know who triggered your event. You could use this information to avoid the unexpected behavior, couldn't you?

Comment: yeah one thought I had was to inspect `event.target.path` which contains the CSS path ... but it seems extremely hacky

Comment: you can use class or id to identify your item (`div` in this case) and access its value through `event.target.className` or `event.target.id` instead of using path. Also I think the `event.stopPropagation` should be enough. If you had a FiddleJS or Plunker it will be easy to help.

Comment: I’ll give that a try thanks